# r data.table - can we use shift() on newly created columns

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to use shift on newly created columns? In for-loop programming, we can access the value of a new column from the previous row. e.g. as below...where I get an error in shift statement since "c" does not exist even though "c" should have been calculated.

```
x <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))
x[,':='(c=a*b, d=shift(c,-1))]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do `x[,c:=a*b][, d:=shift(c,-1)]`?

Comment: I want to conditionally process values of c and use it to derive d. So in other words, the below solution allows to retain intermediate value and then use that to process the next row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to calculate `c` and `d` within `{}`:

```
x <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))

x[,c("c","d"):=({c=a*b; d=shift(c,-1); list(c,d)})][]

   a b  c  d
1: 1 4  4 10
2: 2 5 10 18
3: 3 6 18 NA
```

Comment: just one question...we can not do something like this right? I tried and got error. sounds like can not use shift on newly created variable in same expression.  x[,c("c","d"):=({c=ifelse(a*b<5,a*b,shift(c,-1)); d=shift(c,-1); list(c,d)})][]

Comment: To answer your question : `c` needs to be created before being used, as in normal `R` syntax. So this won't work. Similarly, `ab` isn't defined, it will also cause an error. By the way, I would avoid using `c` as a column name as it might interfere with the `c()`function